# Expression Web and/or ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, expression-web

I have been using Asp.Net for designing web applications recently and was wondering if it would be easier to desing the pages in Expression Web, then open them in Asp.Net to finish coding them. Not sure why they just don't have one tool instead of so many that do almost the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. I have been using Visual Studio for quite a while and found switching to expression web to even make simple HTML mockups a pain. I found the behavior in expression web a bit different. e.g. it does not seem to auto-complete the tags, the intellisense behavior feels a bit different, etc.

I guess I might have been missing some setting but learning a new tool to achieve something which I can already achieve in Visual Studio seems like a pain when the new tool doesnt seem to offer any extra benefits.

If you are comfortable with Visual Studio, I don't see any need to move onto Expression Web

Comment: That was pretty much same conculusion I came up with too, although I've only been trying Expression Web for one day.